# Error: com.example.uklon_android D 400 Bad Request when sending a photo to the server

Tags: java, android, asp.net-core, retrofit2

Throws a 400 Bad Request error when sending a photo to the server. I am sending via retrofit 2 to the server. I download the photo from my phone in png format and try to upload it to the server. Please help who can. Below will be the code for Android and the server (AspNet Core 6.0):
Code Android:

```
selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            // Отримайте фактичний шлях до вибраної фотографії і використовуйте його
            imagePath = getPathFromUri(selectedImageUri);


            // Отримайте файл з фактичним шляхом
            File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imageFile", imageFile.getName(), requestFile);

            UploadDTO uploadDTO = new UploadDTO();
            uploadDTO.setImageFile(body);
            uploadDTO.setUserId(correctUser.getId());

            Log.d("user id:", uploadDTO.getUserId());
            Log.d("image:", String.valueOf(uploadDTO.getImageFile().body()));

            RequestBody userIdRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), correctUser.getId());

            apiService.uploadPhoto(uploadDTO).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                    if(response.body() != null)
                    {
                        // Тут ви можете робити що завгодно з вибраною фотографією, наприклад, відображати її у віджеті ImageView
                        avatarImg.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                        urlAv = imagePath;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("Error: ", String.valueOf(response.code() + " " + response.message()));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

UploadDTO:

```
package com.example.uklon_android.DTOs;

import java.io.File;

import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import retrofit2.http.Part;

public class UploadDTO {
    String userId;
    MultipartBody.Part imageFile;

    public void setUserId(String userId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    };

    public String getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setImageFile(MultipartBody.Part imageFile)
    {
        this.imageFile = imageFile;
    };

    public MultipartBody.Part getImageFile()
    {
        return imageFile;
    }
}
```

Code in server:

```
[HttpPost("upload-photo")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPhotoAsync(UploadDTO upload)
        {
            if (upload.imageFile == null || upload.imageFile.Length == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No file uploaded.");
            }

            try
            {
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(upload.imageFile.FileName);

                // Шлях для збереження файлу на сервері
                var filePath = Path.Combine("uploads", fileName);

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await upload.imageFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

                // Ви можете зберігати шлях до файлу в базі даних або повертати його як відповідь
                string imageUrl = "/uploads/" + fileName;

                // Пошук моделі за ідентифікатором
                var existingModel = await _context.Users.FindAsync(upload.userId);

                if (existingModel == null)
                    return NotFound();

                // Оновлення полів моделі
                existingModel.Url = imageUrl;

                // Зберегти зміни
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                return Ok(existingModel);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { error = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

UploadDTO in server:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BissnesLogic.DTOs
{
    public class UploadDTO
    {
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public IFormFile imageFile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please tell me what could be the problem?

I don't understand what could be wrong

Comment: I don't see any user authentication, just the easy to forge userId. Are you sure this is an open API where everybody without having an account can upload images?

Comment: @Robert Yes, this is an open API, tomorrow I can reset the controller code where this method is, if necessary

Comment: for .net core api `public async Task<IActionResult> UploadPhotoAsync(UploadDTO upload)`, it requires the request to post `formdata`, you might have a test with postman to call the api seperately, and I'm afraid that it would work because your code of the api looks good.